# PHP -Google Charts cannot read my data from database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to create a chart from the database data but when i call the data it won't displayed. I would like to ask is any wrong with my code? 
Is the sql statement wrong because i have tried checked the code and seem everything look great.
Now i have three table which is review, users and upload_medicine. The review table is link users and upload_medicine primary key which is user_id and medicine_id respectively. 
In the chart i intend to call the total of user from review table and call the illness name from the upload_medicine.

```
//connect to database
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","authen");

  $sql4="select * from review left join upload_medicine on review.medicineid=upload_medicine.medicine_id left join users on review.userid = users.user_id ";
$result4=mysqli_query($db,$sql4);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> TCHM </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style01.css"/>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Bil', 'Illness'],
          <?php
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc(result4)){
                echo"['".$row['sum(userid)']."',".$row['illness_name']."],";
            }
            ?>
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'The total user faced the illness'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

  </script>
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: is mean the the code is different version? i should change the version?

Comment: It's just another way of writing exactly the same code with the same library. It's shorter, it's easier to read, and you won't forget an `i` and acidentally use the wrong library.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Comment: Instead of smashing out stuff with `echo` try using [`json_encode`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on an array. Writing JSON by hand is almost always a huge mistake. As always, check your JavaScript console, plus your PHP server error logs.

Comment: Because i'm fresh in this field, i cant understand with the json_encode. In school only teach echo and sql. Sorry i still cannot understand what you are trying to explain to let me clear and understood.

Comment: If you're in school, that's great, you're there to learn, and one of the best ways to learn is by reading the manual. Every function is extensively documented, including `json_encode`. If you're having trouble using it, that's something we can help with. If you haven't even tried, that's next on your things to do list.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you advise and i knew it i should improve myself to extend my knowledge.